# APEX 5: How can I store the results of a MultiSelection from a List in an APEX-Item?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

My example list:

[image: multi-select list]

How can I store the results in the Input Field "Your Choose" as comma-separate values (in this example: ALABAMA, ARIZONA).

Would APEX_UTIL.TABLE_TO_STRING be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific while asking questions.

I assume that you have page with

1. item `PX_MULTISELECT`.
2. process `Before Header` that loads data from DB to the input `PX_MULTISELECT`

And basing on this I assume you are asking how to get data separated with `:` from DB.

In process that loads data you should fetch data from db using listagg function

```
begin
  select
    listagg(COLUMN, ':') within group (order by 1)
  into
    :PX_MULTISELECT
  from
    ...
  where
    ...
 end;
```

[LISTAGG documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)